# Make a direct phone call in Windows Phone 8.1 (w/o user involving)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, phone-call

I'd like my windows phone application to make a phone call.
I found the following API:

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.PhoneCallManager.ShowPhoneCallUI(number, name);
```

But the code above just open a UI with a question "would you like to call..." but don't perform the call itself.
Do you know if there is an API for such option to simply call a number form my app, w/o invloving user?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't know Windows Phone programming but i think think that such a thing is impossible and also illegal

Comment: Being able to call w/o involving user will introduce very nasty apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible with the current API (and I guess it never be).